# Android-Kotlin: best way to start and stop a cyclic execution of a task, repeating it every few seconds from its conclusion

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

*My goal:*

in the view of the fragment I have a button that, when pressed once, launches a method in the viewModel which cyclically calls a suspend function to be repeated every few seconds from its conclusion. Pressing the button again stops this cycle.

*My approach:*

inside the **fragment** I set the onclicklistener of the button

```
binding.demoButton.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.toggleDemo()
        }
```

in the **viewModel**:

```
 private var startDemo : Boolean = false //I need to know whether to start the loop or stop it
 private var isBusy : Boolean = false //I need to know if my task is running or finished

fun toggleDemo(){
        val oldValue : Boolean = startDemo
        val newValue = !oldValue
        startDemo = newValue
        if(startDemo){
            saveLogLine("** start demo **") //method that passes some log strings to the fragment
            startDemo()
        }else{
            saveLogLine("NO start demo!!")
        }
    }

private fun startDemo(){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            saveLogLineAsync("before while loop")
            while(startDemo){
                if(!isBusy){
                    isBusy = true
                    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                        runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO) {
                            saveLogLineAsync("inside runBlocking")
                            initDemo()
                        }
                        isBusy = false
                        saveLogLineAsync("inside handler")
                    }, 5000)
                }

            }
            saveLogLineAsync("after while loop")
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initDemo(){  //my task
      
    }
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

I would have liked to use a Service () or a BroadcastReceiver () but in both cases I would not know how to make them communicate with the fragment or with the viewModel (more precisely, they should be able to use the 2 methods 'saveLogLineAsync' and 'intDemo')

Comment: Do you want to call `initDemo()` after 5 sec with blocking behaviour?

Comment: yes, so I'm sure it first executes the initDemo () method and then sets the isBusy variable to false. Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: Would the alternative have been to replace runBlocking with Globalscope.launch and put 'isBusy = false' inside the initDemo () method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code with this:

```
    private var demoRunning = false
    private var demoJob: Job? = null

    fun toggleDemo() {
        if (!demoRunning) {
            startDemo()
        } else {
            demoJob?.cancel()
        }
        demoRunning = !demoRunning
    }

    private fun startDemo() {
        demoJob = viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            while (true) {
                initDemo()
                delay(5000)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun initDemo() {  //my task
        Log.e("INIT DEMO", "initDemo Ran")
    }
```

Comment: You can further simplify by omitting the Boolean and using the null state of `demoJob` to determine whether there is a running job. Set it to null after cancelling.

Comment: @Tenfour04 oh yeahhh! Awesome man! :D But then it will require `demoJob=null` in the `else` clause.